# Is there any problem with the following Python+TF+Keras code for a custom loss function and network?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, loss-function, autoencoder

I am trying to code a custom loss function for variational autoencoder. I am not using mse for reconstruction loss since I am **not** learning `p(x|z) ~ N(mu,I)`. Instead of that, I want to learn the `sigma` as well. So `p(x|z)~N(mu,sigma**2I)`. If I consider this, then my reconstruction loss function part changes to include additional items: `input_dim*ln(2*pi)` and `(x-mu)**2/(sigma)**2`  along with the KL divergence term. `(x-mu)**2/(sigma)**2` is equivalent to `0.5*input_dim*mse(input,output)/sigma**2`.

My question is, with this modification, is my code valid.

```
def loss(inputs,outputs):
    # Note log_var = ln(sigma**2)
    
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
    
    log_var = K.Variable(0.0)
    
    reconn_loss = 0.5*input_dim*(mse(inputs,outputs)/K.exp(log_var)+log_var+ np.log(2*np.pi))
    
    #kl loss
    kl_loss = -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    
    vae_loss = K.sum(reconn_loss + kl_loss)

    return vae_loss
```

Now the actual encoder-decoder function. Note, since I want to output mu, and sigma from decoder as well, it's architecture is similar to the encoder's.

```
def VAEmodel(params):
    input_dim = params['input_dim']
    latent_dim = 2
    intermediate_dim = 32
    intermediate_dim_2  = 16 # extra added Delete later

    # encoder
    inputs = Input(shape=(input_dim,),name='encoder_input')
    x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='relu')(x)       
    z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
    z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)

    # reparametrization trick to sample latent code (z) from Q(z|x)
    z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

    # instantiate encoder model
    encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
    #encoder.summary()

    # decoder
    latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
    x = Dense(intermediate_dim_2, activation='relu')(latent_inputs) # Extra layer added,Delete later
    x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)               
    outputs_mean = Dense(input_dim, activation='linear',name='output_mean')(x)
    outputs_var = Dense(input_dim, activation='linear',name='output_var')(x)
    # instantiate decoder model
    decoder = Model(latent_inputs, [outputs_mean,outputs_var], name='decoder')
    #decoder.summary()

    # instantiate vae model
    outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
    vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')

    #get the loss function
    vaeloss = loss(inputs,outputs)
    #compile
    vae.compile(optimizer= 'adam',loss=vaeloss)

    return vae,encoder,decoder,outputs
```

Note, I can get the mu, and sigma from outputs[0], and outputs[1] respectively.

Is this set up going to work the way I want i,e learn sigma of p(x|z)?

Thank you very much. Your inputs will be greatly appreciated.